# Custom backend url still has "admin" in it

Tags: admin, url, backend

I have a store which has a custom backend configured in `app\etc\local.xml` where the frontname node is changed like so`<frontName><![CDATA[custom]]></frontName>`.

Normally this would generate URLs like this:

- domain.com/index.php/backend/catalog_product/index

But on this shop the URLs look like this:

- domain.com/index.php/***admin***/backend/catalog_product/index/

I an not familiar with the full history of this shop. So I don't know how this part is exactly configured like this. The problem is I can't use services which connect to a specific backend url.

I allready searched in the database and files for "admin" but this gives too much results obviously. I am still looking through the database results because it is possible to check those at least. I also did a check on core file changes. There are no changes to the core.

**How is this configured? And how can I change it to the default way? I still want to use a custom backend url offcourse.**

Comment: Have you checked server configurations, such as nginx? Or, if on Apache, the .htaccess?

Comment: I just checked the .htaccess. I did not check the nginx configuration, because I don't know where too look. It might be unnecessary to check it because I cloned the site to a (apache) test server by copying the files and db, and this copy also has the same problem. Do you have any further suggestions what I can do?

Comment: It could be the magento 'store code', as technically you're in the 'admin' store view. Can you check if System -> Configuration -> Web -> Use Store Codes in URL set to Yes? If so, try it on 'no'

Comment: @RickyOdinMatthews Yup, thats it! The store does use this function in the frontend so I need to configure this the right way. Thank you very much.

Comment: no worries, I've added this as an answer - if you could accept that would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I might have been too fast. Changing this has implications to the storefront configuration. I added a comment on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the magento 'store code', as technically you're in the 'admin' store view. Can you check if 
`System -> Configuration -> Web -> Use Store Codes in URL` set to `Yes`? If so, try it on 'no'

Comment: This does solve the URL problem for the backend. But I need to use the storecodes in the frontend. I see I can't configure this on storeview level. Can I configue this in such a way so I do use the storecodes in frontend and don't use them in the backend?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is a Global setting in Magento. The 'admin' you're seeing would normally appear as admin/admin on default settings.